# How to skip Safari only Guest asking for firmware password?

Tags: startup, guest-account, firmware-password, restart

I was trying to enable guest account in Mac. When clicking guest account in login screen, the Mac asked for a restart to enter Safari only mode.
I have selected yes to restart and the Mac now asks for firmware password after restart. How I can skip this and go back to the old login screen again?

*Additional details*

In the Mac, these are enabled:

- Firmware password
- File vault

OS : 10.15

Accidentally, I do not remember the firmware password :( and I want to go back to the old login screen.
I suspect that the Mac is now trying to boot from some other startup disk for *Safari only Guest mode*?
Is there any way to go back to the original startup disk, which will not ask for the firmware password?

Comment: A normal reboot didn’t require the firmware password?

Comment: Yeah @nohillside, I think a normal reboot shouldn't ask for it. I don't know why it is asking for firmware password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no going back. You have to enter the firmware password.
Or you can reset it by going to Apple store https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT204455